# How do I show child elements in front of parent element using z-index and opacity?

Tags: html, css, overlay, z-index, opacity

Could someone explain to me how I can show my text "I would like to go" and "select" above the blueish color overlay that I have created over my image, so that they do not appear greyed out? (please see picture). I know that I can achieve this using z-index and opacity, but these text elements are child elements of my overlay, and I read that you cannot set a child in front of a parent element. How would I go about this in my code?

[image]

This is my html/css:

```css
.panorama {
  height:100vh;
  min-height:900px;
}

.panorama-overlay {
  min-height:900px;
  background: rgba(133,216,206,0.57);
  opacity: 0.57;
}

.panorama-activity-select-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align:center;
  /*line-height: 450px;*/
  display:inline;
  margin-left:2em;
}

.panorama-activity-select {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  width: 424px;
  height: 57px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top:0.2em;
  margin-left:3em;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.select-activity-arrow {
  position:absolute;
  right:18em;
  top:-3.7em;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.build-roadtrip-text {
  width: 258px;
  height: 42px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:35px;
  margin-top:3em;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="panorama" style="background: url({{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'panorama.png']) }}) no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center;">
    <section class="panorama-overlay">
      <div class="vertical-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p class="panorama-activity-select-text">I WOULD LIKE TO GO</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p class="panorama-activity-select">SELECT</p>
              <img src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'select-activity-arrow.png']) }}" class="select-activity-arrow"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-offset-6">
            <p class="build-roadtrip-text">BUILD MY ROAD TRIP</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section><!-- panorama navigation section end -->
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, but you can always use a higher `z-index`

Comment: There's no issue with the text's opacity, the overlay is the only thing with an edited opacity. Just make the text and select have a higher z-index than the overlay

Comment: Use multiple backgrounds. See my answer.

Comment: "I read that you cannot set a child in front of a parent element" This is exactly the opposite of true. Children stack on top of their parents by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see here that you set:

```
background: rgba(133,216,206,0.57);
  opacity: 0.57;
```

so you set both the opacity of the background AND the opacity of all childs in the DOM; as to say:
the first set the opacity of the stylized element itself, the second the elemnt and other stuffs, so they are not interexcangable.
Even though they might be used together, i don't see the utility here.
I'd better use

```
background: rgba(133,216,206,0.57);
```

alone, in order to solve the opacity problem of childs..

Comment: Removing the double opacity leaving the reast of the code intact solved my issue , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong.

```
.panorama-overlay {
  min-height:900px;
  background: rgba(133,216,206,0.57);
  opacity: 0.57;
}
```

the opacity:0.57 is set to the parent of the text. So it also applies to its children. Hence the text appears to be greyed.

**Do it this way:**
You can always use multiple backgrounds in background: of css.

So just use the linear-gradient property to overlay the color on the image background.

Replace your background in .panorama:

```
style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(133,216,206,0.57),rgba(133,216,206,0.57)), url({{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'panorama.png']) }}) no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center;"
```

Then final code will be:

```
<section class="panorama" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(133,216,206,0.57),rgba(133,216,206,0.57)), url({{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'panorama.png']) }}) no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center;">
    <section class="panorama-overlay">
      <div class="vertical-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p class="panorama-activity-select-text">I WOULD LIKE TO GO</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p class="panorama-activity-select">SELECT</p>
              <img src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'select-activity-arrow.png']) }}" class="select-activity-arrow"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-offset-6">
            <p class="build-roadtrip-text">BUILD MY ROAD TRIP</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section><!-- panorama navigation section end -->
```

and 
change your css.

```
.panorama-overlay {
  min-height:900px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**update**

```css
.back
{
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url("http://cdn.p-r-i.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/09120259/Meetings2.jpg") no-repeat center;
}
.title 
{
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:200px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class='back'>
  <h1 class='title'>yevadura ?</h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the point in making it via gradient? Especially, when you are make a gradient from one color to exactly the same color?

Comment: I don't understand why anyone downvoted my answer.
@Den why don't you try it yourself. 
You can't directly overlay a color on  a background image using background:rgba(r,g,b,a), url('some.jpg');

But you can use a linear-gradient to do so. So, we are just trying to overlay the color with linear-gradient(same-color).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the point where you have made a common mistake

```
.panorama-overlay {
  min-height:900px;
  background: rgba(133,216,206,0.57);
  opacity: 0.57;
}
```

Let's have a look into `rgba(133,216,206,0.57)` - it is a color indicator with alpha channel which specifies the opacity of the color itself, so the last letter "a" (in "rgba") goes for `0.57` at the end of value of this indicator. By declaring this in your CSS you create a 57% transparent "blueish" color and put it over your image.

However, you are placing another option for this element - the overall opacity with declaration of `opacity: 0.57`. By this you make the "blueish" color of background be 57% more "blueish" and also you are making all the elements within the `panorama-overlay` be 57% more transparent.

Quick answer would be:

1) Remove `opacity: 0.57;`

2) Make `background: rgba(133,216,206,0.23);`

3) Adjust the opacity within the background to the way you like it

Comment: I am a dork for not having seen the double opacity ...... :/ that was the issue, it was so easy .... feeling almost bad to have asked a question for this, haha, thanks! problem solved

Comment: @Benny for years I have thought that it was too stupid of me to ask simple questions here, and you may not believe me, but i really did asked them after all) take it easy and have a good day ;)

Comment: ;) glad to hear I am not alone on this, thanks! have a good day as well